# RegEx to validate nginx location URI pattern

Tags: regex, nginx

I need a regex handler which verifies that given string always starts with forward slash (/) and have two of them, with not ending on the same.
Here is example

### valid

```
/abc/def
/abc-def/ghi
/abc-def/ghi-jkl
/abc-def/ghi-jkl?v=1
```

### invalid

```
//abc/def
/abc/def/
/abcdef/
/abc/def/ghi
/abc-defghi-jkl
/abc-defghi-jkl?v=1
```

I tried some regex , but could not really understand how to test multiple condition in a single expression.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

use this pattern

```
^\/[^/\r\n]+\/[^/\r\n]+$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/258)

```
^               # Start of string/line
\/              # "/"
[^/\r\n]        # Character not in [/\r\n] Character Class
+               # (one or more)(greedy)
\/              # "/"
[^/\r\n]        # Character not in [/\r\n] Character Class
+               # (one or more)(greedy)
$               # End of string/line
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, can you please explain it also. I want to build an understanding on how to club multiple condition in a single regex.

Comment: thanks again... so here is what I understood. If there are multiple conditions, put them under [ ] , like we have two of them in regex you gave. right?

Comment: it matches a beginning of string '\' followed by non '\' followed by '\' followed by non '\' to the end of string